# How to login in a HTTPS page from android

Tags: java, android, html, jsp, httpsurlconnection

I want to login to a website (https://example/logPage.jsp) which requires user and password, then read the html content.

I have tried to send a POST request but I always recibe the html of the logPage.jsp.

This is what I have:

```java
   private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        String cad="";
        InputStream is = null;

        int len = 500;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();


            SSLContext sc;
            sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.connect();

            conn.getOutputStream().write(("username=" + user).getBytes());
            conn.getOutputStream().write( ("password=" + password).getBytes());

            is = conn.getInputStream();


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String line;

            while (((line = in.readLine()) != null)){
                cad=cad+line+"\r\n";
            }

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }

        return cad;
    }
```

This is the html of loginPage.jsp:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...            
    <div class="signin">
      <form name="account"  action="control" method="post" autocomplete="off"> 

      <div class="login_field">

      <label>User          :</label>
      <input id="username" maxlength="64" name="username" class="text"   type="text">

     <div id="username_errors" class="form_errors"></div>
      </div>    

  <label>Password:</label>
  <input id="password" maxlength="64" name="password" class="text"    type="password">
  <INPUT type='hidden' value='E_' name='user_type'>
  <input id="login"  class="super-emphasize"
       value='Send' name='valid_account'  type="submit">
  <div style="display: none;">
</div>
...
 </html>
```

Comment: try using http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Take a look at: http://oauth.net/2/ . Asking users for their username/password from a third-party website is a security anti-pattern. A user should only log-in using the official website / app of the given website, with OAuth being used to ask for and grant access to third-parties.